# How to select multiple rows without using JPQL?

Tags: jpa, select

I am using JPA, so to get one row of data, I could do:

```
Person p = this.em.find(Person.class, 123);
// Note: 'em' is the EntityManager.
```

But how can I get multiple rows? How can I get something like SQL's `SELECT * FROM people WHERE age>18;`?

I know how to use JPQL to get multiple rows (in this case, all rows):

```
TypedQuery<Person> q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p", Person.class);
List<Person> results = q.getResultList();
```

But is there a way to do this without having to write the JPQL (i.e. `SELECT p FROM Person p`) at all?

Note: This is a learning exercise. I want to stick with Jakarta EE only (no Spring or any other API that is outside Jakarta EE).

Comment: I can guess, you are not interested in using Criteria API either, right?

Comment: @amseager I am new to JPA, so I'm open to any standard solution.

Comment: You can use [spring data jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#preface).

Comment: you can use http://www.querydsl.com/

Comment: Why without using jpql.

Comment: If you are looking for "standard" way, `CriteriaQuery` is one standard way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Criteria API as an alternative to JPQL:

```
// Imports.
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

// Example usage of the Criteria API to get a list of all Persons in the database.
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);
cq.select(root);
TypedQuery<Person> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<Person> allPeople = q.getResultList();
```

where `em` is a `javax.persistence.EntityManager`.

Note: Most people use JPQL instead of Criteria API because JPQL (e.g. `SELECT p FROM Person p`) is far more concise than the code above. But the Criteria API has an advantage over JPQL in terms of type safety.

### Further reading

- Tutorial from Oracle: [Using the Criteria API to Create Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria.htm)
- Examples on Wikibooks: [Java Persistence/Criteria](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria)
- [Javadoc for `javax.persistence.criteria`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/persistence/criteria/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

`CriteriaQuery` is the way to go, however another "standard" approach is:

```
// imports

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
@NamedQuery(
    name = "Person.queryAll",
    query = "SELECT p FROM Person p")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

The benefit of using the **criteria** is that errors can be detected earlier. Compile time vs Run time. However, a lot of readers/devs find JPQL easier to use and understand.
Using `CriteriaQuery` will look like below:

```
//skipping imports & config
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

  CriteriaQuery<Person> q = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
  Root<Person> c = q.from(Person.class);
  q.select(c);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware  of `@NamedQuery`, but it involves JPQL. I didn't know about `CriteriaQuery`. Can you give a small example of `CriteriaQuery`?

Comment: @Flux look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Example of CriteriaQuery API:

```java
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
            Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);
            criteria.select(root);
            criteria.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), 123));
            List<Person> people = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

[official docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-typedquery-entity)